# Set React state from Meteor data

Tags: reactjs, meteor, state

developers! Can someone help me please?
I'm trying set `state` in React from Meteor data and edit this `state` data from input, it looks like

---

```
class Profile extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.editProfileBind = this.editProfile.bind(this);
    this.testEmailBind = this.testEmail.bind(this); }

  testEmail(e){
    const input = e.target;
    this.setState({
      email: input.value
    });
    input.value = this.state.email;
  }

  editProfile(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  }

  render(){
    return(
         <form className="col-md-4 col-xs-6" 
             onSubmit={this.editProfileBind}>
             <input type="email"
                  onChange={this.testEmailBind}
                  value={this.props.email || ''}
                />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
   )
 }
}  // end component

export default createContainer(() => {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    const email = user.emails && user.emails[0].address;

    return { email };
}, Profile);
```

Can you suggest me how can I set `this.state.email` to input instead `this.props.email`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple issues with the code:

**1. Intialize state with props**

In the constructor, you need to set your initial state to the `email` prop being passed in.

**2. Input `value` should equal `this.state.email`**

The value isn't updating because you are setting the value to the prop being passed in (which doesn't change) instead of the `email` state that your `testEmail` function is updating.

**3. Update State with new props**

You need to add a `componentWillReceiveProps` function that updates your `email` state when new data is passed into the `Profile` component.

The `Profile` component should look like this:

```
class Profile extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.editProfileBind = this.editProfile.bind(this);
    this.testEmailBind = this.testEmail.bind(this); 
    this.state = {
        email: props.email
    }
  }

  testEmail(e){
    const input = e.target;
    this.setState({
      email: input.value
    });
  }

  editProfile(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        email: nextProps.email
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
         <form className="col-md-4 col-xs-6" 
             onSubmit={this.editProfileBind}>
             <input type="email"
                  onChange={this.testEmailBind}
                  value={this.state.email}
                />
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
   )
 }
}  // end component

export default createContainer(() => {
    const user = Meteor.user();
    const email = user.emails && user.emails[0].address;

    return { email };
}, Profile);
```

Comment: Thanks @Chase, it works! So reason about static email was that I used props ... Thanks, also can you suggest some material to learn about React?

Comment: wonderful! Hey chase, is there a problem with conditionally setting state in componentWillReceiveProps.
I.e. checking if loading is done and only then setting it.

Comment: @FabianBosler That's fine to do, but it would be better to have a `loading` check in the parent components `render`.